# Font Icon Picker Repeater Field is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using This(http://titosust.github.io/Bootstrap-icon-picker) icon picker but this works fine with single field but as soon as I use this in repeater field it does not work .

So far my approach

```
$(".icon-picker").each(function() {$( this ).iconPicker();});
```

I am using jquery ui drag and drop field.

Comment: Please share complete relevant code including HTML also

Comment: The above code should work. What error do you get in console? Also make sure you have class `icon-picker` set to all fields.

Comment: Yes but I am using wordpress and when I add new block it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The approach described in that homepage documentation should work just fine for multiple inputs:

```
$(".icon-picker").iconPicker();
```

because that `iconPicker` handler applies to all the elements selected by the jQuery selector - `$(".icon-picker")`.

I've created a jsFiddle to demonstrate this here: http://jsfiddle.net/vyder/32peyguc/

Let me know if you have any questions.

---

Also, if you take a look at [the jQuery documentation for `each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) you can see that the callback function can expect two inputs - `index` and `element`. So your approach might work like this, but I haven't tried it out:

```
$(".icon-picker").each(function(index, element) { $(element).iconPicker(); });
```

But it's unnecessarily complicated though.